# problems with optparse and python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, optparse

Since upgrading to Python 3.4.3 optparse doesn't appear to recognise command line options. As a simple test i run this (from the optparse examples)

```
# test_optparse.py
def main():
    from optparse import OptionParser

    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
                  help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_option("-q", "--quiet",
                      action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
                      help="don't print status messages to stdout")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    print(options)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run test_optparse.py -f test I get

```
{'verbose': True, 'filename': None}
```

But running within my IDE i get

```
{'filename': 'test', 'verbose': True}
```

I first noted this in a script where I concatenated a run command, for example;

```
run_cmd = 'python.exe ' + '<path to script> + ' -q ' + '<query_name>'
res = os.system(run_cmd)
```

But when I displayed the run_cmd string it displayed in the interpreter over 2 lines

```
print(run_cmd)
'python.exe <path to script> -q '
' <query_name>'
```

So it may be that the passing of the command line is being fragmented by something and only the first section is being passed (hence no query name) and so the run python script fails with 'no query specified'.

I've changed all this to use subprocess.call to get around this, but it useful to have the run_query script for command line use as was. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You know [`optparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html) has been deprecated since 2.7/3.2?

Comment: [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) is the way to go

Comment: also [docopt](http://docopt.org/) might be something to consider.

Comment: I did not know that optparse has been deprecated - I do now. I'll move to one of the 2 suggested. Thanks

Comment: ok - having done that - I have the same issue. I'll raise separately

Comment: here - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393656/cant-pass-arguements-using-argparse-and-python-3-4-2-on-windows-7)