# can't pass arguements using argparse and python 3.4.2 on Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I've upgraded to Python 3.4.2 and argparse (from optparse) but neither appears to recognise command line options. As a simple test I run this;

```
#test_argparse.py

def main():
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Execute database query.')

    parser.add_argument("-q", "--query", dest="query",
                  help="Name of the query file to be run")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

From the command line, when I run

```
test_argparse.py -q get_msre_for_book
```

I get:

```
Namespace(query=None)
```

But when I run from within the IDE:

```
*** Python 3.4.2rc1 (v3.4.2rc1:8711a0951384, Sep 21 2014, 21:16:45) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. ***

Command Line : -q get_msre_for_book
Namespace(query='get_msre_for_book')
```

I'm trying to launch the script via

```
os.system('python.exe', '<path to script>test_argparse.py -q get_msre_for_book')
```

But that fails as no query is presented as shown above. I've worked round this by launching using

```
subprocess.call
```

but I'd rather not have to. Again, any suggestions or ideas gratefully received.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows command line issue.  I'd import `sys`, and print `sys.argv` to check the commandline strings that the parser has to work with.

Comment: ok having added

`print(sys.argv)` when I run `test_argparse.py -q get_msre_for_book` I now get   `Namespace(query=None)` and `['Y:\\Python\\test_argparse.py']` 

So it does indeed appear to be something wrong with the command line.

Comment: and in the ide
`Command Line : -q get_msre_for_trader_book2` 
`Namespace(query='get_msre_for_trader_book2')` 
`['Y:\\Python\\test_argparse.py', '-q', 'get_msre_for_trader_book2']`

Comment: But on another Windows 7 box, running optparse and Python 2.6.6 it works as expected `(<Values at 0x20c81e8: {'query': 'test'}>, [])
['N:\\Python\\test_optparse.py', '-q', 'test']`

Comment: There are earlier SO questions about passing commandline arguments in Windows 7.  The solutions involve getting a registry link right.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880540.  e,g, `"C:\Python\Python33\python.exe" "%1" %*.`

Comment: That fixed it - thank you very much - but to be precise the registry entry needs to be `C:\Python\Python33\python.exe" "%1" %"` (added the final double quote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give closure to this question, these are the 2 comments that solve the problem:

> There are earlier SO questions about passing commandline arguments in Windows 7. The solutions involve getting a registry link right. stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971, stackoverflow.com/questions/9880540. e,g, "C:\Python\Python33\python.exe" "%1" %*.
>
> That fixed it - thank you very much - but to be precise the registry entry needs to be C:\Python\Python33\python.exe" "%1" %" (added the final double quote)